# Ethereum (Solidity) Compiler Output

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm very new to Solidity compiler (and Ethereum).
And my goal is to publish some contract on blockchain.
I'm doing simple example like this: https://ethereum.gitbooks.io/frontier-guide/content/compiling_contract.html

But this line:

> contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test

doesn't work as in example. Because property "test" is always unavailable.

Instead of .test it returns key like this:

[image: eth console output]

I can't understand what is "/tmp/geth-compile-solidity255557006:test:".

> $geth version
>
> Version: 1.5.6-unstable
>
> Protocol Versions: [63 62]
>
> Go Version: go1.7.3

Answer (score 1):

I suggest if you're starting in solidity to first try using the online compiler https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ which lets you choose the solidity compiler version and have a better compilation issues navigation system

Answer (score 0):

you can consider using [truffle](http://truffleframework.com/) and CLI tool

Because the `eth.compile.solidity` has been dropped in latest version.

Comment: I also think that you should start with truffle and testrpc to do everything local first, then, when you get used to, go to the real deployment